# A purely ajax-oriented front-end paradigm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, web

I am new to web development. I am considering `a general working paradigm` for front-end web pages as below:

[image]

1. First, client will request server on some URL, and server will return a `pure static HTML page` to client. Note that this static HTML page MUST be readily wired up with CSS and Javascript. It may contain `placeholders` that will be filled later.
2. Second, once the page is loaded in the client browser, an `init()` script will be invoked and send an AJAX call to the server's RESTful API. The server will respond some data to client for initial display. i.e. to fill the placeholders in step 1.
3. Now client page is ready with all placeholders filled. Customer can view the page and perform activities on it. These activities can trigger *ad-hoc* AJAX calls to the server's RESTful API to get necessary data.

I think this paradigm has the following benefits:

1. The initial response is quick because it is purely static HTML and no server-side process involved for the first request.
2. No need to learn various detailed syntax such as JSP, Expression Language, scriptlet, etc.
3. Simple development paradigm. Server side just need to provide an `init()` API and other business-related APIs, all RESTful.

Is this paradigm OK? Is there any `limitations or flaws`?

### ADD 1

Some more thoughts:

If the `placeholders` are only meant to be replaced by some `non-interactive` content, it may be easy to let the JS generate some HTML fragment after obtaining necessary data through calling server RESTful API. But if the `placeholders` are for some `complex and interactive` content, maybe it's not that easy to generate proper HTML fragment. i.e. `It may be not easy to create a complex UI component with JS on client side`.

Or is this idea of generating HTML fragment a wrong approach?

### ADD 2

A related thread:

[Pros and cons of an HTML/JavaScript only web app](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147423/pros-and-cons-of-an-html-javascript-only-web-app)

Comment: It's terrible if you need SEO. For a pure web *application* (that doesn't need any non-static content indexed by search engines) it's fine. For a web *site* - not so much.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Why it is bad with SEO? And yes, I am indeed working on a internal project which is a pure web `application`. Not many people will use it.

Comment: Because search engines usually only index the static content. They don't always run  JavaScript (google does run some JS in some cases, but probably not everything)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Though there're dynamic `placeholders`, I think maybe the static HTML content already contains enough info for SEO.

Comment: I am under the mental process/struggle to understand the approach of modern web application architecture. And sometimes my brain is not that cooperative. So please, do not close this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're a masochist, I'd look into using a modern single page app web framework, many of which achieve very much what you are planning, but will save you a lot of boiler-plate effort.

Examples include:

Angular JS:  https://angularjs.org/ 
ReactJS: https://facebook.github.io/react/ 
SailsJS: http://sailsjs.org/
Backbone.js
Meteor.js
Knockout.js

etc.  I'd start with Angular and work from there..

Here's a decent list:

http://noeticforce.com/best-Javascript-frameworks-for-single-page-modern-web-applications

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not planning to reinvent the wheel. Since I am new to web development, I just want to confirm if my idea is a sound one. And so far, it seems not that ridiculous. :)

Comment: I think your idea is sound, which is why many of these frameworks are already doing it, and have solved the problems you'll need to solve.